# Linear Interpolation and Object Collision

Tags: c++, animation, mfc, game-physics, linear-interpolation

I have a physics engine that uses AABB testing to detect object collisions and an animation system that does not use linear interpolation. Because of this, my collisions act erratically at times, especially at high speeds. Here is a glaringly obvious problem in my system...

For the sake of demonstration, assume a frame in our animation system lasts 1 second and we are given the following scenario at frame 0.

[image]

At frame 1, the collision of the objects will not bet detected, because c1 will have traveled past c2 on the next draw.

[image]

Although I'm not using it, I have a bit of a grasp on how linear interpolation works because I have used linear extrapolation in this project in a different context. I'm wondering if linear interpolation will solve the problems I'm experiencing, or if I will need other methods as well.

There is a part of me that is confused about how linear interpolation is used in the context of animation. The idea is that we can achieve smooth animation at low frame rates. In the above scenario, we cannot simply just set c1 to be centered at x=3 in frame 1. In reality, they would have collided somewhere between frame 0 and frame 1. Does linear interpolation automatically take care of this and allow for precise AABB testing? If not, what will it solve and what other methods should I look into to achieve smooth and precise collision detection and animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenon you are experiencing is called **tunnelling**, and is a problem inherent to discrete collision detection architectures. You are correct in feeling that linear interpolation may have something to do with the solution as it can allow you to, within a margin of error (usually), predict the path of an object between frames, but this is just one piece of a much larger solution. The terminology I've seen associated with these types of solutions is "Continuous Collision Detection". The topic is large and gets quite complex, and there are books that discuss it, such as [Real Time Collision Detection](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/books/rtcd/toc/index.html) and other online resources.

So to answer your question: no, linear interpolation on its own won't solve your problems*. Unless you're only dealing with circles or spheres.

### What to Start Thinking About

The way the solutions look and behave are dependant on your design decisions and are generally large. So just to point in the direction of the solution, the fundamental idea of continuous collision detection is to figure out: How far between the early frame and the later frame does the collision happen, and in what position and rotation are the two objects at this point. Then you must calculate the configuration the objects will be in at the later frame time in response to this. Things get very interesting addressing these problems for anything other than circles in two dimensions.

I haven't implemented this but I've seen described a solution where you march the two candidates forward between the frames, advancing their position with linear interpolation and their orientation with spherical linear interpolation and checking with discrete algorithms whether they're intersecting (Gilbert-Johnson-Keerthi Algorithm). From here you continue to apply discrete algorithms to get the smallest penetration depth (Expanding Polytope Algorithm) and pass that and the remaining time between the frames, along to a solver to get how the objects look at your later frame time. This doesn't give an analytic answer but I don't have knowledge of an analytic answer for generalized 2 or 3D cases.

If you don't want to go down this path, your best weapon in the fight against complexity is assumptions: If you can assume your high velocity objects can be represented as a point things get easier, if you can assume the orientation of the objects doesn't matter (circles, spheres) things get easier, and it keeps going and going. The topic is beyond interesting and I'm still on the path of learning it, but it has provided some of the most satisfying moments in my programming period. I hope these ideas get you on that path as well.

**Edit:** Since you specified you're working on a billiard game.

First we'll check whether discrete or continuous is needed

- Is any amount of tunnelling acceptable in this game? Not in billiards
  no.
- What is the speed at which we will see tunnelling? Using a 0.0285m
  radius for the ball (standard American) and a 0.01s physics step, we
  get 2.85m/s as the minimum speed that collisions start giving bad
  response. I'm not familiar with the speed of billiard balls but that
  number feels too low.

So just checking on every frame if two of the balls are intersecting is not enough, but we don't need to go completely continuous. If we use interpolation to subdivide each frame we can increase the velocity needed to create incorrect behaviour: With 2 subdivisions we get 5.7m/s, which is still low; 3 subdivisions gives us 8.55m/s, which seems reasonable; and 4 gives us 11.4m/s which feels higher than I imagine billiard balls are moving. So how do we accomplish this?

### Discrete Collisions with Frame Subdivisions using Linear Interpolation

Using subdivisions is expensive so it's worth putting time into candidate detection to use it only where needed. This is another problem with a bunch of fun solutions, and unfortunately out of scope of the question.

So you have two candidate circles which will very probably collide between the current frame and the next frame. So in pseudo code the algorithm looks like:

```
dt = 0.01
subdivisions = 4
circle1.next_position = circle1.position + (circle1.velocity * dt)
circle2.next_position = circle2.position + (circle2.velocity * dt)
for i from 0 to subdivisions:
   temp_c1.position = interpolate(circle1.position, circle1.next_position, (i + 1) / subdivisions)
   temp_c2.position = interpolate(circle2.position, circle2.next_position, (i + 1) / subdivisions)
   if intersecting(temp_c1, temp_c2):
      intersection confirmed
no intersection
```

Where the interpolate signature is `interpolate(start, end, alpha)`

So here you have interpolation being used to "move" the circles along the path they would take between the current and the next frame. On a confirmed intersection you can get the penetration depth and pass the delta time (dt / subdivisions), the two circles, the penetration depth and the collision points along to a resolution step that determines how they should respond to the collision.

Comment: Thank you for such an in-depth response. I'm making a billiards game, so all of my collisions (with the exception of the pool cue hitting the ball) are with circles. I have come quite a long way with my naive approach, but to advance further I must improve on it. I think these ideas are the next step. I'm still a bit confused about how exactly linear interpolation helps though. If we know the location of an object, and where we need to move it to in the current frame, how can this help if we can't draw between frames (i.e., the 1.5th frame)?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. You're essentially just checking a few frames ahead to predict a potential collision. I'm still not understanding when the collision is drawn though. The user must see the circles actually touch and collide. It still only seems like they will see the result of the collision - where the balls are AFTER the collision occurs.

Comment: You're absolutely right that generally we won't see the, exact moment the objects are touching but surprisingly this happens even in the biggest budget games. The problem is that computers can only update the physics of the game every x seconds, and so objects can always touch at x + x/2 seconds. No matter how small we try to make x, there is always time between frames where objects can be exactly touching and we won't see that point in time. But when x is very small, for example 0.01 seconds, our eyes and brains cannot even perceive that we didn't see that exact moment

Comment: I wondered if this was the case. However, I must wonder how the non-budget games take care of this. Also, in your code, how did you choose the value for dt? This value seems like it needs to be carefully chosen. If we are using 4 subdivisions, then shouldn't our dt = frame length / 4? We need to make sure we're checking all the way up until the next frame, right? This may cause me problems since I update my game based on the amount of time since the last draw using a timer. I'm not sure if I could get away with a rough estimate for frame length, could I?